# NSURLSession Background Download Time limit

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, networking, nsurlsession

As using NSURLSession, we can download data when the application is in the background. For a non-enterprise demo application, I have created a demo project and tested that iOS gives only 180 seconds for performing background task.
Regarding this, I have two questions -

1. For a Non-Enterprise app, Is 180 seconds is the maximum time limit for doing background activity or there is any way to extend this 180 seconds time limit?
2. For an Enterprise app, Is there any such kind of time limitation or we can break all Apple App Review Guidelines?

Comment: I have run into this and verified 180 seconds as well.  Have you found a way to extend this?